# Saving to two different tables in a Create Action Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am doing a basic customer save, but can't figure out how to additionally save the address to my Address table.

Currently in my Create.cshtml view I have all of my primary customer fields such as Name, Phone, Fax, Email. Then additionally added to my form is an EditorTemplate called Address.cshtml which has all of the address fields in it.

My overall goal is to create a new Address record in the Address table with the information in the EditorTemplate fields, then create a new Customer record in the Customer table with the primary customer fields values and AddressId from the newly created Address.

I am unsure of what would go into the "[Bind(Include section". Would it be AddressId, or Address.Address1, Address.Address2, Address.City, etc..

Here is what my POST Action Method looks like currently:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Name,Phone,Fax,Email,Address")] Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int addressId = _adminService.SaveAddress(customer.Address);
            customer.AddressId = addressId; 
            _custService.SaveCustomer(customer);
        }
        return View(Edit);
    }
```

Comment: Remove the `[Bind]` attribute. By default all properties are bound, and currently you appear to be excluding the `Address` properties.

Comment: So if I don't go the view model route could I do this? public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Name,Phone,Fax,Email,Address1,Address2,City,StateId,PostalCode")] Customer customer, Address address). I know you said to remove bind but there are fields I don't need such as CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, DateCreated, DateUpdated, etc.

Comment: I recommend a view model, but if you not rendering controls for `DateCreated` etc in the view, nothing will be posted back for them and they will be null, or if you are rendering controls for some reason you can always just ignore them or use `[Bind(Exclude="DateCreated, ...")]`

Answer (score 1):

Also, adding on to what Stephen said....you should create (if you have not already) a view model that encapsulates the properties from both of your views. I would also recommend having the method which creates your Address and Customer objects in the view model.

Comment: I am using EF6 Db First in my Data layer and then I have a Model layer with Pocos/Dtos using AutoMapper. My web project accesses my model layer. So on top of this you are saying to create ViewModels in my Model folder of my MVC5 app which is not being used. In this case it would have only the Customer properties needed and then the Address properties. So lets see... Name, Phone, Fax, Email, Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip. Or would I not include all address fields and just an Address Property since there is an AddressId field in Customer table.

Comment: You should be able to create a view model with just your customer and address DTO objects as public properties. The model binding should populate these for you.

If not, create your view model with the combined properties of both objects as you mentioned. You can still use AutoMapper to map the view model to your objects, though you would end up mapping twice, once for each DTO object.